# Regex to find two words in a text block not (necessarily) in any position/pattern

Tags: regex

If I want to find WordA and WordB in text block but don't care if they are in any order or pattern can I do so?  I know I can do

```
WordA WordB
```

If I want them in that order/pattern or even

```
WordA.*?WordB
```

if i wanted WordB atany point after but ideally I don't want to have to keep doing:

```
WordA.*?WordB|WordB.*?WordA
```

Comment: how about `WordA|WordB`

Comment: @Luke: this pattern can match only WordA or only WordB.

Comment: thats not true @CasimiretHippolyte ? `/WordA|WordB/g` works perfectly on WordA and WordB.

Comment: on a pattern such as "asdf WordA asdf WordB", /WordA|WordB/g will identify the words inside of the string, but not the string itself as a match.

Comment: @Luke: indeed, but you can't be sure that there are WordA AND WordB in the same string.

Comment: @tezromania: it is not necessary to "identify the string itself" since you know what is the string at the begining. A method/function (regex or not) that returns true or false should suffice.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte So in this case they would need to split into a word form and iterate, and then keep flags based on whether each individual word had yet been encountered?

Comment: @tezromania: Why not? But the method you suggested do the job: `^(?=.*\bWordA\b)(?=.*\bWordB\b)` with a match method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use your suggested pattern, and additionally would need some extra .* matching in it as well like so:

```
(.*WordA.*WordB.*)|(.*WordB.*WordA.*)
```

Alternatively, the method of using look-aheads to do this would look something like this, and seems to be a little more complex:

```
^(?=.*?\bWordA\b)(?=.*?\bWordB\b).*$
```

I would also like to mention that perhaps your language has a string.contains method in it that could be used like so:

```
String testString = "asdf WordA asdf WordB asdf";

if(testString.contains("WordA") && testString.contains("WordB"))
{
    // here we have a positive match
}
```

Comment: I am using regex php.  I tried your second method ^(?=.*?\bWordA\b)(?=.*?\bWordB\b).*$ and it works great thank you. I added a groupname to the beginning which closes  on the end of WordB to identify when the string found both words and then a namegroup to WordA to extract that (WordB is the Anchor that qualifies A), i.e http://regex101.com/r/jF4qI8